# Spanning the title of a bootstrap 4 card group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap card group with a title.  Currently, the title is within a card, but I would like this to span over the card group.  How can this be done?

```
        <div class="card-group">
            <div class="card border-right-0 border-top-0">
                <div class="card-header bg-white border-bottom-0 h5 font-weight-light">Project Status Overview</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1 class="card-text text-primary text-center">@ViewBag.ActiveProjects</h1>
                    <p class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Active Projects</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card border-right-0 border-top-0">
                <div class="card-header bg-white border-bottom-0 h5 font-weight-light">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1 class="card-text text-secondary text-center">@ViewBag.ArchivedProjects</h1>
                    <p class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Archived Projects</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card border-right-0 border-top-0">
                <div class="card-header bg-white border-bottom-0 h5 font-weight-light">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1 class="card-text text-warning text-center">3</h1>
                    <p class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Pending Dimensions</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card border-top-0">
                <div class="card-header bg-white border-bottom-0 h5 font-weight-light">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1 class="card-text text-success text-center">32</h1>
                    <p class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Estimates Available</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using [Flex box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). Wrap the `.card-group` div in a flex box div, and then move the title div outside the `.card-group` div.

Example

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="bg-white border-bottom-0 h5 font-weight-light">title</div>
  <div class="card-group"><!-- cards here --></div>
</div>
```

When using `display: flex;` (`.d-flex`), the title div will align with the `.card-group` div.

Solution:

```
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="bg-white border-bottom-0 h5 font-weight-light">Project Status Overview</div>
    <div class="card-group">
      <div class="card border-right-0 border-top-0">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h1 class="card-text text-primary text-center">23</h1>
          <p class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Active Projects</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card border-right-0 border-top-0">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h1 class="card-text text-secondary text-center">5</h1>
          <p class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Archived Projects</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card border-right-0 border-top-0">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h1 class="card-text text-warning text-center">3</h1>
          <p class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Pending Dimensions</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card border-top-0">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h1 class="card-text text-success text-center">32</h1>
          <p class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Estimates Available</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Jsbin example here: https://jsbin.com/xeyiroyasa/edit?html,output